# bootstrap carousel (auto-slide doesn't work)

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

Hope you have a nice day! I have a problem every time I run that , it appear only the first slide for few seconds then it disappears completely and when I use the side arrows or the buttons before the slide disappears it works normally.

HTML

```
<header>
        <div class="row row-content">
            <div class="col">
                <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img src="img/img1.png" class="d-block img-fluid">
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" alt="img1">
                                <h2>text</h2>
                                <p class="d-none d-sm-block">text</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img src="img/img2.png" class="d-block img-fluid">
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" alt="img2">
                                <h2>text</h2>
                                <p class="d-none d-sm-block">text</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img src="img/img3.png" class="d-block img-fluid">
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" alt="img3">
                                <h2>text</h2>
                                <p class="d-none d-sm-block">text</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       
                        
                    </div>
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#mycarousel"data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#mycarousel"data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#mycarousel"data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <a  class="carousel-control-prev" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a  class="carousel-control-next" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

CSS

```
.carousel-item {
  height: 420px;
}
.carousel-item img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 420px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made this example and is working perfectly. Have you inserted js library? Because your code is all right.

```css
.carousel-item {
  height: 420px;
}
.carousel-item img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 420px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <header>
            <div class="row row-content">
                <div class="col">
                    <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                            
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <img src="https://www.lupadigital.info/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/imagens-gratis.jpg" class="d-block img-fluid">
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" alt="img1">
                                    <h2>text</h2>
                                    <p class="d-none d-sm-block">text</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="https://www.lupadigital.info/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/imagens-gratis.jpg" class="d-block img-fluid">
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" alt="img2">
                                    <h2>text</h2>
                                    <p class="d-none d-sm-block">text</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="https://www.lupadigital.info/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/imagens-gratis.jpg" class="d-block img-fluid">
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" alt="img3">
                                    <h2>text</h2>
                                    <p class="d-none d-sm-block">text</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                           
                            
                        </div>
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#mycarousel"data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#mycarousel"data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
                            <li data-target="#mycarousel"data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
                        </ol>
                        <a  class="carousel-control-prev" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a  class="carousel-control-next" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.
actually this is what I included in my project :

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
scripts

Comment: <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

Comment: Browser doesn't give you an 404 error? I changed my code like yours, and it just worked. Verify if it found every file.

Comment: You're welcome, anything ask us for helping!